# Iron python script to remove some columns from a crosstable visualization in spotfire

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

I have few views listed and every time a user select a view few columns need to be excluded from the cross table visualization in the spot fire. I am new to spot fire so was searching for any method or Iron python script to perform the same

Answer (score 0):

An example of your report would help to provide a better answer.

If you can pass the view selected as a document property, then have a python script fire off when that document property changes, pull in the cross table as a parameter as well as that document property, and change the axis expressions as desired. A sample script is below:

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import *
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import *

myVis = myVis.As[Visualization]()

if viewSelected == "View A":
    # Horizontal:
    myVis.ColumnAxis.Expression = "<[Column 1]>"

    # Vertical:
    myVis.RowAxis.Expression = "<[Column 2] NEST [Column 3]>"

    # Cell values:
    myVis.MeasureAxis.Expression = "Sum([Actual]), Sum([Forecast])"
elif viewSelected == "View B":
    # Horizontal:
    myVis.ColumnAxis.Expression = "<[Column 4]>"

    # Vertical:
    myVis.RowAxis.Expression = "<[Column 5] NEST [Column 6]>"

    # Cell values:
    myVis.MeasureAxis.Expression = "Sum([Plan]), Sum([Difference])"
else:
    # Horizontal:
    myVis.ColumnAxis.Expression = "<[Column 7]>"

    # Vertical:
    myVis.RowAxis.Expression = "<[Column 8] NEST [Column 9]>"

    # Cell values:
    myVis.MeasureAxis.Expression = "Sum([Forecast]), Sum([Plan])"
```